# Backing up my filesystem with 500GB of data. One big tarball or many small tarballs?

Tags: linux, backup

I have 500GB of data that I want to compress into an encrypted gpg tarball and backup onto multiple storage devices including external hard drives and cloud storage.

Is it better to backup my entire filesystem into one big tarball or to backup each folder on my filesystem into a bunch of small to medium sized encrypted tarballs?

I would prefer to do one big tarball because it'd just be easier to deal with but I'm concerned about data corruption. Intuitively if my big tarball gets corrupted I lose everything but if I have 100 or so tarballs instead and data gets corrupted I only lose a small portion of my file system. (Is this right? Maybe I'm wrong? I have no idea).

Comment: Use a proper backup tool. There is a ton of things you don't consider when you start something like this and there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gerald Schneider wrote, use a proper backup tool.

Also, the risk of your backup being corrupted is greatly reduced if backing up is not a one-off event but part of your regular schedule, and if you follow the 3-2-1 principle when backing up: Three copies, on two different media, with at least one off-site copy.

Using a proper backup tool will also assist in the most important part of a backup routine: Ensuring that the backups actually work.

Comment: Whats a good backup tool?

Comment: Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic for this forum (https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) but you should be looking for something that can create and keep track of the lifecycle of multiple generations of backups, and validate backups to some degree (at the very least checksumming compared to the original content but preferably one that supports scripted restore tests). Often you would look at different products for VM environments than for physical servers and workstations.